# mysql jdbc connection with ssl

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

hello i am able to connect remote database using tcp/ip over ssh through in mysql workbench

but i am unable to connect in java program can u give me reply my code is here what i have to add in that please reply

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.10:3306/soa</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
```

192.168.1.10 ip address of remote database 
soa is database name 
root & root is password username and password of mysql 
3306 default port

Answer (score 0):

when you create the connection to your URL, need to define some properties related with the ssl key you are going to use. Example:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", "root");
props.setProperty("password", "root");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",
"D:\\truststore\\truststore.jks");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
props.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","welcome123");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props); 
//your code
```

If you are using hibernate:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/service_name"/>
    <property name="user" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="connectionProperties>
        <value>
        oracle.net.ssl_cipher_suites: (ssl_rsa_export_with_rc4_40_md5, ssl_rsa_export_with_des40_cbc_sha)
        oracle.net.ssl_client_authentication: false
        oracle.net.ssl_version: 3.0
        oracle.net.encryption_client: REJECTED 
        oracle.net.crypto_checksum_client: REJECTED
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <!-- classes etc -->
</bean>
```

Comment: how to do in hibernate

Comment: jdbc url that specifies ssl connection can yu tell briefly

Comment: <property name="URL"><value><!-- JDBC URL that specifies SSL connection --></value></property>
    <!-- other relevant properties, like user and password -->

Comment: can u describe briefly

Comment: @venkatakrishnareddymedam i added few more details, but is an initial example of how could you start, now you need to research for something specific to your db,. properties, config,...